# IF this or this or this?

Tags: apex, compile-error, conditional, if

I am trying to implement the below code, but I get this error:

> OR operator can only be applied to Boolean expressions

Code:

```
public class Segment {
    static List<Map<String, Object>> jsonMAP = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
    public string    SegName         {get; set;}
    public string    jsonstring = ' ';
    public integer   List_id         {get; set;}
    public string[]  conditionsARRAY {get; set;}
    public string    customfield     {get; set;}
    public string    fieldname       {get; set;}
    public string    operator        {get; set;}
    public string    age = '0';
    public string    andor = 'and';
    public void Maker(){

        for(integer i=0; i<=99; i++){
            if(i == 0||4||8||12||16||20||52||56||60||64||68||72){ //<--Line 15 with error
                customfield = 'Type';
                fieldname   = 'Buyer';
                operator    = 'eq';
            }
            if(i == 24||28||32||36||40||44||48||76||80||84||88||92){
                customfield = 'Type';
                fieldname   = 'Seller';
                operator    = 'eq';

            }
            if(i == 1||5||9||13||17||21||25||29||33||37||41||45||49||53||57||61||65||69||73||77||881||85||89||93||97){
                customfield = 'Age';
                if(i)
                fieldname   = age;
                operator    = 'eq';
            }
            if(i == 2||6||10||14||18||22||26||30||34||38||42||46||50||54||58||62||66||70||75||78||82||86||90||94||98){
                customfield = 'zAuto';
                fieldname   = '1';
                operator    = 'eq';
            }
            if (i == 3||7||11||15||19||23||27||31||35||39||43||47||51||55||59||63||67||71||76||77||83||87||91||95||99){
                customfield = 'DateAdded';

            }
            if (customfield == 'DateAdded'){operator='lt'; andor=' '; fieldname = age;}

        Map<String, Object> conditions = new Map<String, Object>{
            'field'   => customfield,  //custom field to filter by
            'value'   => fieldname,
            'operator'=> operator,
            'and_or'  => andor
        }; jsonmap.add(conditions);

        }
        conditionsARRAY = json.serialize(jsonmap);
        jsonstring = '{"name":"' + SegName + '","list_id":' + List_id+ ',"conditions":'+ conditionsARRAY +'}';

       } 


}
```

Comment: You will have to get funky with math class, use sets and check if contains or something else. It expects `i=1 || i=2 || i=3` as you cannot use `1||2||3||4` unless i was a boolean and you were actually OR'ing the values which it does not appear you are trying to do

Comment: Just so you know, you can select a whole code block and indent it properly if you just hit the `{}` button in your editor. Alternatively, hit `CTRL + K` (`⌘ + K` on a mac).

Comment: Also you have a random seeming `if (i)` clause in the middle of all that which may give you separate issues...

Answer (score 5):

You have two basic options:

- Use the `Set.contains` method
- Join complete logical clauses

The first strategy would look like:

```
Set<Integer> multiplesOf4 = new Set<Integer>{0,4,8,12,...};

for (Integer i = 0; ...)
{
    if (multiplesOf4.contains(i))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The second strategy would look like:

```
if (i == 0 || i == 4 || i == 8 || i == 12 || i == ...)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, if you squint your eyes, the provided code kinda looks like [FizzBuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz).

Using sets (as per Adrian's example) is probably the way to go here...but I'm not writing this answer to be efficient...just purely logical (with a bit of whimsy thrown in for good measure).

Since all of your target values in a given group are *always* multiples of 4 away from another one, you could simplify your expressions a bit using `Math.mod()`.

```
// This syntax is invalid, no matter how much we would wish it to be valid
//if(i == 0||4||8||12||16||20||52||56||60||64||68||72){

// This is equivalent
if((i <= 20 || (i >= 52  && i <= 72) && Math.mod(i,4) == 0)){
```

using that same idea, we can convert your other statements as well

```
//if(i == 24||28||32||36||40||44||48||76||80||84||88||92){
if((i >= 24 && i <= 48 || i >= 72 && i <= 92) && Math.mod(i, 4) == 0){

//if(i == 1||5||9||13||17||21||25||29||33||37||41||45||49||53||57||61||65||69||73||77||81||85||89||93||97){
if(Math.mod(i, 4) == 1){

//if(i == 2||6||10||14||18||22||26||30||34||38||42||46||50||54||58||62||66||70||75||78||82||86||90||94||98){
if(Math.mod(i, 4) == 2){

//if (i == 3||7||11||15||19||23||27||31||35||39||43||47||51||55||59||63||67||71||76||77||83||87||91||95||99){
if(Math.mod(i, 4) == 3){
```

Ok, so that wasn't as bad as I thought it might be at first. One aspect of being a good programmer is being able to see patterns like this. The simpler the pattern, the simpler the code (can be). Notice how when we broke the pattern in the first 2 conditions, the if statement got longer. At some point, it would definitely be better to use sets instead of `Math.mod()`.

In this example, using sets would lead to faster execution...but with you only looping 100 times, the difference would be so negligible as to not be worth consideration.

Another thing that I see you doing a lot in your questions is using repeated `if()` statements where `else` or `else if()` would be more appropriate. In your example code, there is no situation where you would want to enter another conditional block after you enter one of them. Using `else if` and `else` will save a negligible amount of CPU time, but the more important thing is that *using `else if` and `else` mean that you won't find yourself entering more than one of those conditional blocks*.

Doing that could help make your code more robust. It also might mask some logical errors (which could be a good thing, or a bad thing, depending on your perspective).

```
// Better implementation.
// Code is probably the shortest possible for the situation (though not the fastest
//   running)
if((i <= 20 || (i >= 52  && i <= 72) && Math.mod(i,4) == 0)){
    // some code
} else if((i >= 24 && i <= 48 || i >= 72 && i <= 92) && Math.mod(i, 4) == 0){
    // some code
} else if(Math.mod(i, 4) == 1){
    // some code
} else if(Math.mod(i, 4) == 2){
    // some code
} else if(Math.mod(i, 4) == 3){
    // some code
} else {
    // some code for what should happen if none of the conditions are met.
    // This else block is optional, but I'd argue that explicitly stating what
    //   happens in every possible case is good practice.
}
```